# Using yq delete list item and parent node if list becomes empty

Tags: yaml, yq

I have fields with example values.

**EDIT: there are other nodes at the root level (siblings of `fields`) that I need to retain, too.**

- If a value is empty, I want to remove the parent list item
- If there are no examples left, I want to remove the entire examples node
- The examples may have other fields of their own, but I just want to follow the two rules above no matter what

### Input

```yaml
project: people_ages
fields:
  first_name:
    examples:
      - value: Jon
        comment: A very common name
  last_name:
    examples:
      - value: ''
        comment: Where is his last name?
  age:
    examples:
      - value: 22
        comment: Just got out of college
      - value:
        comment: Not sure about his age
```

### Desired output

```yaml
project: people_ages
fields:
  first_name:
    examples:
      - value: Jon
        comment: A very common name
  last_name:
  age:
    examples:
      - value: 22
        comment: Just got out of college
```

Using Go version of yq - [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of `to_entries/from_entries` builtins, with `map` and `select`

```bash
yq '.fields | to_entries | map(select(.value.examples[].value != "")) | 
        map(select(.value.examples | length >0)) | from_entries' yaml
```

The `to_entries` method converts the objects into a key/value pair with `key` and `value` prefixed as key names respectively and `from_entries` does the opposite of it. Between the two, the logic to exclude the objects containing `.value` as empty string is applied. And when the previous transformation is complete, we now exclude at the `.examples` level to consider those objects that have non-zero entries.

---

Per updated requirement added to the question to retain other fields and keeping the original YAML structure intact, suggest using the update select operator `|=`

```bash
yq '.fields |= (to_entries | map(select(.value.examples[].value != "")) | 
        map(select(.value.examples | length >0)) | from_entries)' yaml
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you believe I left something out that I thought wouldn't matter!? There are other nodes at the same level at `fields`, and I need to retain them, too. Will edit question.